# Constructor initializer list is not calling copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, language-lawyer, copy-elision

So I was learning about constructor initializer list and I wrote the following code :

```
class Mango
{
  public:

  Mango(){cout<<"Mango::ctor()";}
  Mango(const Mango& other){cout<<"Mango::copy_ctor()";}
};

class Box
{
    public:

    Box() : mango(Mango()) //**doesn't call copy constructor**
    {
    }

    Mango mango;
};

int main()
{
  Box box; 

   return 0;
}
```

I used g++ compiler for this. Its calling the constructor not copy constructor. It should call copy constructor right because I am creating an object to create another object? What's the issue here and what does standard says about it?

Comment: The default constructor is called because you do `Mango()`. What then happens is [*copy-elision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).

Answer (score 18):

Because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), the copy-construction is omitted here. This behavior is guaranteed from C++17. Before C++17 it's not mandatory; the compilers are permitted, but not required to perform copy elision<sup>1</sup>.

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy- and move- construction of class objects even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. They need not be present or accessible, as the language rules ensure that no copy/move operation takes place, even conceptually:
>
> - In initialization, if the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object:
>
>   ```
>     T x = T(T(T())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
>   ```

That means, `mango` will initialized by the default constructor directly.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> In fact most implementations would also perform copy elision before C++17. With [Gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rQQvefyZ1ZgPqnlt) you can try with `-fno-elide-constructors` option in pre-C++17 mode to disable copy elision.

Answer (score 2):

As songyuanyao already explained so well in his excellent answer, the compiler is permitted to optimize away the invocation of the copy constructor in a number of cases.

Still, I'd like to address a different part of your question, just in case there is some misunderstanding:

> I used g++ compiler for this. **Its calling the constructor not copy constructor. It should call copy constructor right because I am creating an object to create another object?** What's the issue here and what does standard says about it?

Your copy constructor needs to be provided with a `(const Mango& other)` in order to be invoked. If the compiler were to not perform copy elision, you would first see a call to the "normal" constructor `"Mango::ctor()"` followed by a call to the copy-constructor `"Mango::copy_ctor()"`. Copy elision merely optimizes away the unnecessary copy-constructor call - the constructor for the object needs to be called in either way in order to get the `Mango()` object in `Box() : mango(Mango())`